# "NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://localhost/magento2/pub/media/"?

Tags: magento2, permissions

i run magento2 get error

> "NetworkError: 404 Not Found -
>   http://localhost/magento2/pub/media/"

i tried run php -f bin/magento setup:upgrade

```
get
missing permissions magento2/pub/media
```

how do fix it. nay help?

Answer (score 3):

Although it might work temporarily in development, you should *not* use 777 permissions. Magento will write new files with a different set of permissions next time it runs.

We recommend 770/660 permissions with ownership split between a local user and the web server user.

[Magento file system owner documentation](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/install-gde/prereq/apache-user.html)

[Recommended file ownership and permissions](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/install-gde/prereq/integrator_install.html#instgde-prereq-compose-access)

Answer (score -1):

give 777 permission to pub/static folder and var folder then run below command to regenerate all css and js file in pub/static folder if you changed code directly in pub folder then you will loss that data because it dynamically generated  files

**bin\magento sampledata:deploy**

Comment: how do set 777 permission to pub/static folder and var folder?

Comment: 777 is a very unsafe recommendation, yes it gets the job done, but leaves users to vulnerabilities.